# How to create a c# Program that Accepts and can distinguish between two clients?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcplistener

I am writing a program that can accept two clients, but creates two different objects for them because they communicate with the server in two different ways. How can I edit this existing program where it can first distinguish what client it is, and then assign it to the appropriate class.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

class MyTcpListener
{
  public static void Main()
  { 
    TcpListener server=null;   
    try
    {
      // Set the TcpListener on port 13000.
      Int32 port = 13000;
      IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
      // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
      server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

      // Start listening for client requests.
      server.Start();

      // Buffer for reading data
      Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
      String data = null;

      // Enter the listening loop. 
      while(true) 
      {
         Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

        // Perform a blocking call to accept requests. 
        // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();            
        Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

        data = null;
        // Get a stream object for reading and writing
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        int i;

        // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client. 
        while((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))!=0) 
        {   
          // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
          data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
          Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);

          // Process the data sent by the client.
          data = data.ToUpper();

          byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

          // Send back a response.
          stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
          Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", data);            
        }

        // Shutdown and end connection
        client.Close();
      }
    }
    catch(SocketException e)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
    }
    finally
    {
       // Stop listening for new clients.
       server.Stop();
    }


    Console.WriteLine("\nHit enter to continue...");
    Console.Read();
  }   
}
```

Comment: I'll recommend the client appending a header in the front of the handshake which identifies the type of client it is. I.E. first byte that client sends = 0 OR 1, depending on the type of client it is.

Answer (score 0):

Say these are Client classes for different clients.

```
public class ClientClassA : IClientInstance
{
}

public class ClientClassB : IClientInstance
{
}
```

Use Singleton Pattern

```
public interface IClientInstance
{
}

public static class ClientInstance
{
    public enum ClientTypes
    {
        ClientTypeA,
        ClientTypeB
    };

public static ClientInstance Create(ClientTypes ofClientType)
{
    IClientInstance clientObject = null;
    switch (ofClientType)
    {
        case ClientInstance.ClientTypes.ClientTypeA:
            clientObject = new ClientClassA() as ClientInstance;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return clientObject;
}
}
```